# Changes on ViewController don't persist from didSelectRowAtIndexPath to cellForRowAtIndexPath on iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift2

**The Code Explanation**

I made a small change on my application (Swift 2.1, xCode 7.2, Deployment Target 8), added a Table with two search options. The behavior can be mapped as:

- On the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, change the `selectedSearchOption` attribute of the **ViewController** and change the `keyboardType`, all based on the selected element. Then, call the `reloadInputViews` (of the vc) and `reloadData` (of the table).

Code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.selectedSearchOption = self.searchOptions[indexPath.item]
    switch selectedSearchOption {
    case SearchOption.ByTeam:
        searchField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation
    default:
        searchField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    }
    searchField.reloadInputViews()
    searchOptionsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

- On the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (called afterwards, because I invoke `reloadData`), I check the `selectedSearchOption` attribute to customize the view of the selected element.

*Code*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(SearchOptionCell.identifier) as! SearchOptionCell

    let searchOption = self.searchOptions[indexPath.item]
    cell.name.text = searchOption.rawValue
    if self.selectedSearchOption == searchOption {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "ic_done_16")
    } else {
        cell.imageView?.image = nil
    }
    return cell
}
```

**The problem:**

The code is working fine on the iPad 2 (8.3) and the iPhone 6 (8.4.1), but on the iPhone 4S (it was 9.something, I updated to 9.3.1), two strange things are happening:

1. The `reloadInputViews` did not change the keyboard type for the user (I already try to call `resignFirstResponder` and then `becomeFirstResponder`).
2. When the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, the `selectedSearchOption` attribute is with his old value, like it was never changed. Crazy as it is, if I debug the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, the value on the VC is correct.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I have a listener to the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` event.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "showKeyboard",
    name:
    UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
    object: nil
)
```

At the showKeyboard method I was reseting the `selectedSearchOption` value. And apparently on the **iOS 9** the `reloadInputViews` method is now invoking the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` event.

To solve the problem I now check if the keyboard is already open using a flag that I update in the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` events. Gladly The `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is not invoked by the `reloadInputViews` method. And then, just if the keyboard is opening I reset the `selectedSearchOption` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna invoke the **reloadInputView**,at first of all I wanna know whether keyboard became first responder before you invoked the methoud of reloadInputView.That’s very momentous …..Hope it’s useful for your issue..